# Python - Random number guessing game - Telling user they are close to guessing the number

Tags: python

I have a quick question. 
I want to make my number guessing game tell the user if they are 2 numbers away from guessing the random number. 
I do not want the program to say how many numbers away the user is. 
The way I'm thinking is this. I just can't put this into proper code.

```
Random_number = 5
guess = 3
print('you are close to guessing the number!')
guess = 7
print('you are close to guessing the number!')
guess = 2 #more than 2 away from the number
print('you are NOT close to guessing the number')
```

Comment: post your *code* (the "way I'm thinking"), and perhaps someone will post their *suggestions*

Comment: Alright, thanks for your suggestion. I think I changed it to a way that is easier to read for other people. Sorry, I"m new here =/

Comment: This can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917097/guessing-game-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Although I appreciate the suggestion, that doesn't solve my problem. I can easily tell the player if his or her guess is too high or too low. 
What I want to do is "warn" the user that they are two or less numbers away from guessing the correct number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to start by saying my python is rusty and someone please fix it if im off alittle.

All you need to do if use an if statement.

```
random = 5
guess = 3
if( guess == random ):
    print('your right!')
elif ( abs (guess - random) <= 2 ):
    print('you are close to guessing the number!')
else:
    print('you are not close enough!')
```

Edited the `elseif` logic according to @9000's suggestion.

Comment: You can directly write `elsif random - 2 <= guess <= random + 2`, or you could compute it as `abs(guess - random) <= 2`, too.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. When this statement is true, everything works. guess <= random+2 | guess >= random-2

Comment: This code won't work.  In your `elif`, you say are basically saying:
3 <= 7
in your first part of the `elif`.  That would evaluate to `True` even though the guess isn't within 2 of the random number.  Your example also doesn't support if the guess is within 1 of the random number.

Comment: Edited to be legit Python, no other changes though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for number in range (2):
    if guess == Random_number:
        print('you guessed the number!')
    if guess - number == Random_number or guess + number == Random_number:
        print('you are close to guessing the number!)
```

Here is the explanation.  The first line is saying "for the numbers in the range of 0 to 2 set number equal to that number."  So the next if part will run 3 times:  for number equaling 0, 1, and 2.  So, if your guess is within 2 of the random number, it will print you are close to the random number.  If you have the correct guess, it will obviously print you guessed it correctly.

Comment: Why do you use a for loop to do a simple integer comparison? Seems like your over complexifying your logic.

Comment: That is the easiest way to do it.  Your example doesn't work in all cases e.g. when the guess is within 1 of the random number.

Comment: It works for all cases. Rand = 5 guess = 4. Abs (5-4) = 1. Which 1 <= 2 equates to true. Using a loop for comparison is not optimal. A loop changes you O time from O(1) to O(x). Using big oh notation, my way is 3 times more optimal.